# backup from 13.10 fails to restore in 14.04

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I had 13.10 and I did a backup with deja-dup of my music, videos, and document folders and saved it to an external drive. I then wiped my drive clean and ran a fresh install with 14.04 now when I try to restore I get the following (below).

Failed with an unknown error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1494, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1488, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1337, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1370, in do_backup
    globals.archive_dir).set_values()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 697, in set_values
    self.get_backup_chains(partials + backend_filename_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 819, in get_backup_chains
    map(add_to_sets, filename_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 809, in add_to_sets
    if set.add_filename(filename):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 100, in add_filename
    (self.volume_name_dict, filename)
AssertionError: ({1: 'duplicity-full.20140419T005410Z.vol1.difftar.gz'}, 'duplicity-full.20140419T005410Z.vol1.difftar.xz')
```

Comment: Try monitoring free space on all filesystems while restoring files (I suggest `watch -n3 df`). Try restoring with `duplicity` setting high `--verbosity` levels.

Comment: Looks a lot like [bug #877631](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/877631) - is it possible your backup got interrupted and you have some duplicate files?

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live 13.10 media available [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/)
mount the partition that you wish to restore the data to then

try the restore. if it fails again, try

`sudo apt-get update' when booted from the live cd

and try again to restore. the suggestion above in the comments about watching df from  int_ua may also prove useful if you are in fact trying to restore more data than you have space for. the suggestion regarding turning on verbosity for duplicity may also gives some clues about the unspecified error which will help us help you.